# Twilio Integration With Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, twilio, twilio-php

I am facing a problem in my project for several days. I want To integrate Twilio for voice conversation in my laravel App. I want That When a User Want to call the twilio account he need a token that is generated from my site.

For Example :

User A Appoints User B for meeting conversation.

User A gets a token after accepting his meeting By User B.

User B also gets a token. User A then call to the Twilio number.

When he call he needs to submit his token.

After submitting User B notified and needs to submit his token to initiate the phone meeting.

This is all I need to do. But dont know how to fix this. Can you guys please give me some advice of how can I achieve this. Sorry For my Bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if all your wanting is the logic, here is how I recommend this be implemented.

1. Meeting creator (John) invites a member of his team (Bob) to his newly created meeting.

The application creates a meeting password for John, saving it in the database. It wouldn't yet create one for Bob because he hasn't accepted the invitation. You can separate "hosts" and "invitees" if you'd like to give them a different experience.

2. Bob receives a notification (text message, email, etc..)

Bob approves the request, and is then generated a meeting password (which is saved to the database).

3. The meeting time is near, so Bob & John dial in to the Twilio phone number that you have provided them. Upon picking up (set your incoming call webhook to the logic in your Laravel application) the Laravel application uses TwiML to ask the user to enter their meeting number, and meeting password (or just password, up to you). At this point, the user enters a valid password.
4. The two calls are connected together using the Twilio API. You don't really need one to wait for the other. Throw them in a conference and let Twilio handle that logic using the [Conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference) and [Conference Participants](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant) REST API.

Let me know if I am missing something else you need in here.